# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Photography's [fourth moderator election](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: MikeW]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learn the ropes!

Please also join me in thanking [chills42](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/67/chills42) and [Rowland Shaw](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21/rowland-shaw) who are stepping down. Both were elected in Photography's [very first election](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/1).

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4612158423826432/0).

Comment: Where is the 2015 Moderator Election questionnaire?

Comment: @dpollitt: Funny story (or more sad, in a way): we forgot to post it. It was poor planning on our part since the election was scheduled to coincide with our one off-site meeting of the year. Here's hoping we will get more of this stuff automated before the next election.

Comment: @JonEricson - To the credit of our two candidates, they answered the whole thread in comments anyways. Where there's a will... :)

Answer (score 5):

In my mind, this was not a high-stakes election, as either outcome would have been great. As it came out, congratulations Mike!

(And thanks to chills42 and Rowland!)

Answer (score 3):

Congrats Mike and welcome to the team!

I've been basically offline all of today, at an Agile conference, but hopefully I can spin up some time to help show you around in the next day or so.

Many thanks to chills42 and Rowland Shaw for all of their time on the site over the years.

Comment: Only if your PO prioritizes it!

Comment: @dpollitt - Ah, but I'm in management, so I get to ignore the priority! :p

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone.  I'll poke around and let you know if I have questions :)

Comment: Created a chat space for us as well. Handy to have now that there's a bit more coordination to consider. @jrista

Answer (score 2):

Congrats, Mike! Welcome aboard!

Feel free to ask questions if you need any help.

I second John's sentiments to chills42 and Rowland Shaw.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats Mike! Enjoy your new review queue options :-P